# What is the rationale behind being able to change the git commit author to anything?

Tags: git

I noticed today that you can you can change the author of a commit to absolutely anything, just by changing the config. It doesn't need to be your username, or even a valid username. Is this not open to some kind of abuse?

[image]

Comment: Yes. This is also why people sign commits with a key for verification. https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/signing-commits

Comment: The thing is, no vcs can prevent this kind of forgery. Git doesn't pretend to have security, the secure method @evolutionxbox mentioned is there for anyone who needs it, but there's no fake security on offer.

Comment: Protect access to the repo from unauthorised users before considering verified commits.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43597805/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/q/8502123/7976758